# How to calculate latent variables from questionaaire?

Tags: spss, inference, factor-analysis

I would like to calculate the stress variable from 6 items (Likert scale questions) in the questionnaire. Cann anyone help me and let me about the method or introduce the reference for learning that?

Answer (score 0):

A latent variable model is a type of structural equation model (SEM), an approach that SPSS can't handle. You could do this sort of modeling using the SPSS add on AMOS, or you could use a variety of other options including *lavaan* or *OpenMx* in R, or MPlus. AMOS does require a license, but I find it to be more approachable for beginners than are some of the other options.

As far as references, this looks like a decent short introduction to structural equation modeling in AMOS (admittedly, I've only skimmed it):
https://stat.utexas.edu/images/SSC/Site/AMOS_Tutorial.pdf

You can also find some good resources listed here: https://openmx.ssri.psu.edu/sem-resources.

Also, you might get more response if you update your question to tag [sem] rather than [spss], because latent variables aren't part of SPSS, so your question might not be getting to the right people.